# Rails confirmation for post method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, confirm

Is there any simple way to add confirmation for post method, I can add for delete but I didn't find a simple solution for post method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for this

```
<%= f.submit 'Save', data: { confirm: 'Your message Here' } %>
```

***Update:***

If you want it for a `button_to`, then the below will work

```
<%= button_to "Save", { action: "create" }, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Your message Here" } %>
```

Comment: I m looking for link_to or button_to, I will use it for a post method within a button_to, it is something like `<%= button_to "Save", action, data: { confirm: 'Your message Here' } %>`